# windows server 2016 core missing vpnclient powershell module

Tags: vpn, powershell, windows-server-2016

I have a fresh install of Windows Server 2016 (without Desktop) and I want to use the Add-VPNConnection powershell command to connect to a VPN network. Apparently Add-VPNConnection is a command of the "vpnclient" module, which is missing from my installation.

how can i install this module ? what am i missing ?

Comment: Did you try `Import-Module VpnClient`?

Comment: yes i did. Get-Module -Listavailable doesn't return VpnClient

Comment: Do you have `PSGet` or `PowerShellGet` module? Try `Get-Module -Listavailable|Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'get|Vpn'}`

Comment: yes, i have PowerShellGet. I have Install-Module. It asks first for an update to be able to check on NuGet, then says it can't find VpnClient

Comment: Odd, I have a 2016 system with the `RemoteAccess` feature installed.  Even that doesn't have the VpnClient module.

Comment: 5 years later.... I have the same issue on 2019 and 2022. I am running Windows Server Core, which seems to be the problem